# Is it okay if my ledger board overlaps my foundation wall?

Tags: deck, ledger

I just got done demoing a 20yo deck that had no footings or flashing. It was constructed of 2x8's on a 2x10 beam cantilevered. So, my design was to be all 2x10's with a flush beam because the deck is not high off the ground, there is a lot of erosion where the deck was and after I grade it I'm pretty sure there is no room for a beam under the deck framing.

So, anyway, this would call for a 2x10 ledger, the problem is that it would overlap the foundation wall by about 2 inches. I planned on using LedgerLoc screws to attach the ledger board and their min distance for bottom screw is 2 inches I think. But they do say that the ledger board should be no taller than the band joist.

The deck is only about 20 inches off the ground, does anyone see a problem with mounting the 2x10 ledger and proceeding as normal or should I shoot some concrete anchors in the overlapping portion or reengineer the whole design (not preferable)?

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Overlapping 2 inches? It is unclear what you are trying to describe.  What does “overlap the foundation wall by 2 inches”  mean exactly? “ flush beam “ ?  How is this beam supported?

Comment: I think you can ignore most of the description. The crux of the post is that the ledger laps down onto the foundation two inches, making fastening more challenging.

Comment: Thank you Isherwood, oh that I could ignore such things.  I was trying to elicit a better description  with more details from the OP.

Comment: What is the span and spacing of the new 2x10 joists onto the new 2x10 ledger? You’ve increased the load on the ledger significantly.

Comment: @isherwood has it right, it overlaps the foundation. Sorry my description was not more clear. The span is 15' 3", joists on 12" centers, triple 2x flush rim beam. I could fasten the ledger board to the foundation wall as well as the band joist. I guess I'm caught up on this from the 2012 code "...the ledger board, which shall be equal to or greater than the deck joist depth but less than or equal to the house band or rim joist depth..."

Answer (score 2):

It's only a problem to the extent that you're hanging common joists on the unsupported portion of the ledger and therefore relying on the integrity of the woodgrain. If your joist hangers only attach on the upper portion, where the ledger is well attached to the framing, I see no concern.

If your hanger attachment extends lower than that, either anchor to the foundation as well or look for structural hardware that carries the entire ledger from the bottom and mounts to the framing. I've used [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-Ledger-Connector-System-ICFVL-W/204842366) on ICF projects, and it would probably work well without the embedded inner portion and the right screws.